# renderizar en contexto diferente en react?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en react+meteor.

El problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un objeto que renderiza dos columnas. En la primera columma (col-lg-4) hay una lista de elementos. En la segunda columna (col-lg-8) quiero mostrar un gráfico que se debe mostrar al pulsar cada uno de los elementos de la primera columna. El problema es que el evento click de cada uno de los elementos (`StockSingle`) ya lo tengo sobreescrito con la carga de datos para cada uno de los gráficos.

Este es el objeto `App`:

```
export default class App extends TrackerReact(Component){

  render(){
    <div className="col-lg-4">
      <ul className="stocks">
        {this.stocks().map(function(stock){
          return(<StockSingle key ={stock._id} stock={stock}/>)})}
      </ul>
   </div>
  <div className="col-lg-8">
   <myChart/>
  </div>
  }
}
```

Este es el objeto `StockSingle`:

```
export default class StockSingle extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      showComponent:false
    }
  }

  clickStock(event){
    this.setState({
      showComponent:true
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <li onClick={this.clickStock.bind(this)}>
      {this.props.stock.name}
      </li>
      {this.state.showComponent?<Loader stock={this.props.stock}/>:null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

El objeto loader carga los datos y muestra un gif spinner mientras esta trabajando:

```
export default class Loader extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getInfo();
  }
  getInfo(){
    //loads the data here...
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="loading">
        <img src="loader2.gif" width='20' height='20' />
      </div>
   )
  }
}
```

No se me ocurre la manera de renderizar el gráfico en col-lg-8 clickando sobre cada uno de los elementos StockSingle. ¿Quizás *reactivevars* de meteor?

Cualquier ayuda es apreciada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás tratando de hacer es una comunicación entre hermanos (sibling communication). Hay varias opciones:

- Usar *context* para hacer disponible propiedades entre una jerarquía (no recomendado).
- Usar el patrón observer/pub-sub. Existen librerías como EventEmitter o Postal que implementan este patrón (recomendado).
- Pasar métodos compartidos como propiedad (recomendado).
- Usar redux/reflux. Esta última opción es factible solo en aplicaciones medianas/grandes o de alta complejidad.

---

La alternativa más sencilla que tienes es definir métodos en el componente padre, métodos que serán compartidos en los hijos.

> **Tip:** trata de no bindear un contexto directamente en el HTML, ya que cada vez que se renderiza el componente creará una nueva instancia de la función lo cual es poco eficiente. En su lugar, haz el bind en el constructor o usa la decoración `@autobind` de [core-decorators](https://npmjs.com/package/core-decorators).

**App**

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      stock: {} // elemento activo
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-lg-4">
        <ul className="stocks">
          {
            this.stocks().map(stock => (
              <StockSingle 
                key ={stock._id} 
                stock={stock}
                notify={this.onStockClick.bind(null, stock)}
              />
            ));
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="col-lg-8">
       <myChart 
         stock={this.state.stock}
       />
      </div>
    );
  }

  /**
   * Será llamado por StockSingle cada vez
   * que se un stock sea pulsado.
   * @param  {SingleStock} stock Stock pulsado
   */
  onStockClick(stock) {
    this.setState({ stock });
  }
}
```

**StockSingle**

```
export default class StockSingle extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      showComponent:false
    };
  }

  clickStock(event) {
    this.setState({
      showComponent:true
    });
    // notificamos que se ha pulsado sobre un stock
    this.notify(this.props.stock);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <li onClick={this.clickStock.bind(this)}>
        {this.props.stock.name}
        </li>
        {
          this.state.showComponent 
          ? <Loader stock={this.props.stock}/>
          :null
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Chart**

```
export default class Chart extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      stock: {}
    };
  }
  /*
   * Este método será llamado cuando se reciba
   * una propiedad desde fuera. Si la propiedad 
   * es otra, actualizamos el estado, causando
   * una re-renderización.
   */
  componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    const { stock } = nextProps;
    if (this.state.stock._id && stock._id !== this.state.stock._id) {
      this.setState({ stock });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <!-- HTML here -->
    );
  }
}
```

Básicamente ocurren tres cosas:

1. Elemento `SingleStock` pulsado. Actualiza su estado y llama a `notify`.
2. Método `notify` de `App` ejecutado. Actualiza el estado cambiando el *stock*.
3. Graph detecta un cambio en sus propiedades. Compara la propiedad *stock* con el *stock* en su estado. Si son diferentes, se re-renderiza.

---

#### Redux

Con Redux es mucho más simple, por ejemplo, solo despachamos una acción y el reducer actualizará el estado. Cuando se pulsa sobre un `StockSingle` despachamos una acción como ésta:

```
const changeStock = stock => {
  return {
    type: 'CHANGE_STOCK',
    stock
  };
}
```

De esta manera (`SingleStock`):

```
this.props.dispatch(changeStock(this.state.stock));
```

Luego, mediante un reducer:

```
const stockReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE_STOCK':
      return Object.assign({}, state, { action.stock });
    default: return state;
  }
};
```

Actualizamos el estado (llamado *store*, que representa el estado de la aplicación, no local) sobreescribiendo el *stock* pulsado. Finalmente, lo obtenemos en `Graph`:

```
@connect(
  state => { stock: state.stock }
)
class Graph extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    this.state = {
      stock: {}
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    const { stock } = nextProps;
    if (this.state.stock._id && this.sate.stock._id !== stock._id) {
      this.setState({ stock });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <!-- HTML aquí -->
    );
  }
}
```

La decoración `@connect` conecta el estado de la aplicación (*store*) con dicho componente. El primer parámetro indica qué datos del *store* queremos que estén disponibles en `Graph`.

---

Redux puede parecer complicado al principio, si estás comenzando con React te recomiendo ir con el primer enfoque.

Comment: Era lo que necesitaba. Muchísimas gracias. como ves soy bastante novatillo con react ..

Comment: ¡ *Peazo* respuesta ! que dicen en mi tierra. +1, y porque no puedo mas :-)